# How can one answer questions in SO so fast?

Tags: discussion, answers

How can one answer questions asked in SO so fast?  I myself try to check if there are any new questions that I can answer, and when I do so, there are already plenty of nice answers.  I do get the chance to learn more and new things, but always have been curious how can one reply so fast (within 1-5 minutes).  I really appreciate SO users who try to answer questions and help us, but what method do you use to do so?

Comment: Funny that your question was also closed and moved to meta within ~50 seconds of being asked.

Comment: great, it does exactly what is says on the tin!

Comment: @seg.server.fault: Well, as far as tools go, I use a browser, a keyboard, sometimes a mouse.  I've been known to go so far as to use a monitor, but that's really a crutch more than a tool.

Answer (score 22):

Ideally:

- It should be a question you already know the answer to
- You should see it very soon after it's posted
- You shouldn't need to find any supporting pages (checking links takes time)
- You should be able to type pretty fast

FWIW, I don't use the RSS feeds or anything like that. I just check the newest questions page reasonably often.

Comment: Yep. My personal record is 53 seconds after the posting of the question. (That one is now my highest-voted answer, just because I have a basic knowledge of data structures and happened to refresh the page at the right time.)

Comment: @mmyers: Was that from posting to answering, or posting to accepting? My personal best for the latter is it still saying "1 minute ago" on the question when I was awarded the Big Green Tick of Goodness.

Comment: Re RSS feed: My impression is that it is **way** slower than the web site.

Comment: No, it wasn't accepted until half an hour later (possibly because it was a negative answer). I don't think I've ever been accepted in less than three or four minutes. But I'd actually rather the asker gave time for answers to settle out before accepting, anyway.

Comment: This explains why Skeet is at top of the chart :)

Comment: My personal best is [24 seconds after the posting of a question while doing a lab test in which I was allowed to browse the site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455768/browsers-think-div-not-ending/5455770#5455770), but I started by submitting a single sentence, so I'm not sure if that counts as cheating :)

Answer (score 12):

`...addiction...`

Answer (score 9):

Sometimes it helps to log on at off-peak hours.  There will be fewer questions, but answers will be slower too (i.e. less competition).  Jeff has said that 8AM-10AM Pacific time is the busiest time--it is when nearly everyone in US/Europe is at work.

Comment: Not only that, but if you quickly give an answer for something reasonably simple, it might stay on the front page for a while and you'll actually get _more_ votes.

Comment: Shouldn't that be a contradiction? Everybody is at work and everybody is monitoring SO for new questions? - I wish I would have time for this at work.

Answer (score 7):

`...dedication...`

Answer (score 4):

Depends on if English is your first language. Mine is not, so it usually takes me a few moments to write something clever. If English was my first language, I could write answers in a few seconds.

Depends on how often you hit refresh.

Answer (score 3):

The refresh button on your browser is your greatest weapon.