# Speedy Questions

Tags: answers, discussion

How do the users on stackoverflow answer so quickly? Are there that many users on at anyone time? I post a question and within a minute get a reply. Are people getting paid to run the site?

Comment: This is the flip side of this coin: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11953/how-can-one-answer-questions-in-so-so-fast

Comment: Some people know exactly what questions [are going to be asked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71501/possible-cheating-via-sock-puppet-account)... ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, there *are* that many users on at any given time, and many of them are experts in their fields. But nobody's getting paid, except in mostly worthless Internet dollars (i.e. reputation points).

Comment: Reputation, my preeeeeccccciiiiiooooouuuuuussssss!

Comment: You should clarify. Nobody is getting paid *by StackOverflow*. Almost everybody who answers questions is getting paid while they do it, their bosses just don't know it :P

Comment: @Brandon, well, the OP _did_ specify "to run the site." But +1 funny.

Comment: TO: POPULAR DEMAND. HELLO DEAR. I am IDRIS ENGA, BARRISTER OF STACK OVERFLOW INC. WE HAVE DECIDED (FOR LIMITED TIME ONLY) TO CONVERT REPUTATION POINTS INTO REAL CURRENCY FOR SELECTED USERS AS A THANK YOU FOR YOUR SERVICE TO THE IT COMMUNITY. TO PARTICIPATE IN THE PROGRAM, PLEASE SEND AN EMAIL CONTAINING name, address, social security number, phone number, and occupation TO stackoverflow_currency_program@hotmail.com LOOKING FOR YOUR SPEEDY REPLY. GOD BLESS, I. ENGA

Comment: TO: IDRIS ENGA. THANK YOU FOR YOUR NOTICE, I DO NOT WISH TO WAIT FOR THE SLOW EMAILING: PLEASE ACCEPT MY DATA NOW Nicholas Riviera - 44 Bow Street, Springfield, USA - 078-05-1120 - (600) 362-8672 - programmer THANK YOU EXTREMELY MUCH I LOOK FORWARD TO MY CHEQUE KINDEST REGARDS Nick (@Rejoice)

Comment: DEAR POPULAR.  THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR TRUST AND WITH GOD'S HELP, WE WILL BE ABLE TO COMPLETE THIS TRANSACTION SOON. I WILL BE GOING TO THE LOCAL BRANCH OF MY BANK TODAY TO POST THE CHEQUE.  ALL THE BEST TO YOU AND YOUR FAMILY. I WILL CONTACT YOU AS SOON AS THE CHEQUE HAS BEEN WIRED FROM MY BANK. PLEASE NOTE DEAR FRIEND, THERE ARE SOME IMPOSTORS CLAIMING TO REPRESENT STACK OVERFLOW IN MY STEAD. NOTE THAT THESE ARE LIARS AND ENEMIES OF OUR MUTUAL BUSINESS ENTERPRISE. I AM THE ONLY REPRESENTATIVE CHOSEN BY THE JEFF ATWOOD. SHOULD YOU RECEIVE SUCH COMMUNICATION PLEASE LET ME KNOW INSTANTLY.

Comment: To: POPULAR DEMAND. DEAR POPULAR. I WENT TO SEE MY BANK BRANCH MANAGER TODAY AND I HAVE GREAT NEWS. AS PER THE DIRECTIVES OF THE JEFF ATWOOD, YOUR  META POINTS WILL BE COUNTED AS WELL. HOWEVER THE FINAL AMOUNT IS TOO LARGE TO BE TRANSFERRED BY bank transfer. I WAS TOLD TO USE SOMETHING CALLED WESTERN UNION FROM YOUR AMERICA. DEAR FRIEND, I AM A SIMPLE MAN AND I DO NOT KNOW THIS UNION. I WAS DOUBTFUL AT FIRST, BUT THE JeFF ATWOOD SAID IT WAS ALL RIGHT AND WE SHOULD ALWAYS TRUST HIM. DO YOU KNOW THIS UNION? DO THEY HAVE A BRANCH IN YOUR CITY? KINDLY REPLY SOON. BLESSINGS TO YOU AND YOUR FAMILY.

Comment: DEAR POPULAR, PLEASE GET BACK TO ME URGENTLY SO WE CAN FINISH THIS TRANSACTION. I HAVE MANY USERS TO TALK TO AND I CANNOT WAIT THIS LONG FOR ONE SINGLE USER.

Comment: MY DEAREST BARRISTER IDRIS, I AM PLEASED AND HUMBLED TO TELL YOU I LIVE IN A VERY LARGE AND IMPRESSIVE CITY. I KNOW BRANCHES OF WESTERN UNION, NORTHERN UNION, EASTERN UNION, SOUTHERN UNION AND WEST-SOUTHWESTERN UNION HERE. AGREED TO TRUST JEFF ATWOOD. PLEASE TO ADVISE, MANY BLESSINGS. REGARDS Nick (@Rejoice)

Comment: DEAR @POPULAR. THANK GOD FOR YOUR REPLY. I AM RELIEVED TO SEE THAT THIS TRANSACTION CAN CONCLUDE IN A TIMELY MANNER. THE JEFF ATWOOD HAS PLACED MUCH TRUST IN ME AND I STRIVE TO FULFILL HIS TRUST TO THE UTMOST EXTENT. I HAVE A DAUGHTER OF FIVE THAT I NEED TO BRING TO THE DOCTOR FOR SOME ROUTINE TREATMENT NOW. AFTER THAT, , I WILL GO TO THE WESTERN UNION OFFICES AND SEND THE MONEY IN FULL. I WILL PRAY TO OUR LORD FOR THE MONEY TO SAFELY ARRIVE IN YOUR HANDS. BEST REGARDS, IDRIS.

Comment: TO ALL THOSE CONCERNED. THIS CONVERSATION HAS BEEN LABELED POINTLESS BY THE INTERNATIONAL COMMITTEE OF DECIDING WHETHER OR NOT CONVERSATIONS ARE STUPID. AKA THE ICDWNCAS. NOT TO BE CONFUSED WITH THE INTERNATIONAL CAT DEPUTY ON WRONGLY NOMINATING CALIFORNIA ASSOCIATES TO SENATE.

Comment: @TylerChacha +1 for ICDWNCAS. +10000 if you can pronounce the acronym.