# How do top users have time to answer several thousand questions? Do they get paid for that?

Tags: discussion, answers

I can see top users who have reputation upwards of 300,000.

For example:

1. [jon-skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) - 341K reputation.
   Answered 15194 questions (so far).
2. [marc-gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell)  -249K reputation.
   Answered  8327 questions (so far).

There are many more.

Surely they have a career, are in a very high position, and will be busy most of the time.

How do they have time to answer so many questions per day? They have to spend their precious time answering, thereby losing hours spent in the office.

So, my question is:

Does stackoverflow officially pay them for answering questions?

(Forgive me if my question is absurd. I was simply curious.)

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/555/why-does-jon-skeet-never-sleep for Jon Skeet's explanation of how he has time to post on SO.

Comment: Well, they have to spend the Venture Ca-unicorn dollars on something...

Comment: We *do* get footrubs from Jeff though, once we meet IRL like on a DevDay? Don't we? I've been accumulating rep solely on that premise

Comment: That reminds me, I should get back to work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Speedy Questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71460/speedy-questions)

Comment: Who is the a**hole who removed Jon Skeet's explanation pointed to by @mmyers? It doesn't matter that the Wayback Machine took a [snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20110817015414/http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/555/why-does-jon-skeet-never-sleep) of it. Whoever removed that question is a digital scumbag.

Comment: @DanDascalescu: The question's title should be a pretty big hint as to why it was deleted.

Comment: It seems the question is not available anymore on the Wayback Machine either. However, someone quoted Jon's answer [here on skeptics](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/14125/25930).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are not paid, at least Jon isn't. They're just doing it for fun, and they are here for a long time. I have posted 1189 answers in 3 months. It's not so hard

Answer (score 14):

Jon Skeet is beyond space and time.

He's also an expert on C#, one of "**the**" experts.  It's no problem for him to post 20 in-depth answers per day quickly, it just flows from his brain fully formed with no thought required.  Or something like that.

Someone with his skills can also do whatever work he wants and name his price, to a degree.  If he wants to spend some time on SO no one's going to stop him.

Of course, I don't know what Jon, Marc, etc. currently do for a living or what their situations are.  Maybe they're actually poor and live in the local library, answering questions from an old Pentium II.  But somehow I doubt it.

(Check out mmyers' link!)

Comment: Jon works for Google (on Java, actually). Marc has worked for SO since sometime in early 2010.

Comment: Maybe there is reason to worry after all. For example, Marc states that he lives in a *forest*. And as to Jon's alleged home town - what kind of place name is *Reading*? On to #3, Darin Dimitrov's gravatar is a pint of beer. The list goes on and on!

Comment: In Jon's case - it's a commute by train with a 3G netbook. He describes the process in one of the podcasts

Comment: @mmyers' link is dead because some SO overlord idiot deleted it.