# Are the people with highest reputations being paid by the Stack Overflow for answering?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do top users have time to answer several thousand questions? Do they get paid for that?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104908/how-do-top-users-have-time-to-answer-several-thousand-questions-do-they-get-pai)

The other day i was discussing about this community with my friends. One of my friend happen to know one of the top rankers in reputation league and he was claiming that he being paid by the Stack Overflow guys for answering questions. Is this true?

Comment: same ? [do-the-people-with-highest-reputations-are-being-paid-by-the-stackoverflow-for-a](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11359899/do-the-people-with-highest-reputations-are-being-paid-by-the-stackoverflow-for-a)

Comment: I doubt it. In my own experience, SO can be so addictive that getting paid to answer would actually be a turn-off for me. If I didn't have any other work to do I'd happily stay and post all day for free.

Comment: The [top 3 user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) and the [top 14 user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/13249/nick-craver) indeed are employed by Stack Exchange Inc. (the company that runs Stack Overflow), but as *developers*, not as answerers.

Comment: @PresleyDias: He was directed to post it here. Technically it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 9):

**No.** Some of the [SE employees](https://stackexchange.com/about/team) (who work on the software which runs the Stack Exchange network) also happen to [answer questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell?tab=answers) and have a high reputation, but they get paid as **developers**, not for answering the questions themselves.

Maybe he was getting confused with that.

Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18888/why-do-you-post-to-stack-overflow